# Azure AD users unable to execute Sitecore PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell-extensions, azure-ad

We are having issues with the execution of PowerShell scripts that have security permissions based on roles applied to them, when they are executed from within a context menu within Content Editor.

When the script is clicked, the script window does not open, and the page is refreshed and reset to the root.

This is only happening for Azure Active Directory users. If we use regular Sitecore user accounts that are members of the required roles, they are able to execute the scripts without any problems. We are using PowerShell Extensions 5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research, we discovered the following PR targeted at version 6.2 https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/pull/1227. We applied the fix to our 5.0 version, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been logged [here](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/1102) and the response is

> The purpose of the Elevated Access is to (optionally) require the user to input a password. If the developer or admin would not know the password then there is little value in using this feature.

Comment: The issue reported by Martin has nothing to do with Elevated Access